# Validación formulario vuejs con Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, formularios, validación

estoy intentando validar un formulario vuejs con Bootstrap, pero no consigo saber cómo he de declarar las variables. La app consta de varios componentes y en el que se encuentra el formulario recibe como prop un array template con los campos. La cuestión es que genero el formulario iterando los elementos del array template, pero no sé cómo definir las variables en data como para asociarlas correctamente. He probado a definirlas directamente, pero cada componente tiene un nombre distinto de campos, por lo que tendría que declarar las variables mediante el template y no con un nombre fijo. El código del formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div v-if="visible" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <form :class=" { 'was-validated': isValidated }" class="my-3 col-md-7 col-lg-9 g-3 mx-auto" @submit="sendForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group d-lg-flex mb-3" v-for="i in template.data">
                <label :for="i.promtp" class="d-none d-md-block d-md-block col-lg-3 col-form-label text-right">{{i.prompt}}</label>
                <div class=" col-lg-9">
                        <input v-if="i.type == 'text'" type="text" class="w-100" v-model="i.value" :id="i.prompt"  :placeholder="i.prompt" required>
                        <input v-if="i.type == 'date'" type="date" class="w-100" v-model="i.value" :id="i.prompt"  :placeholder="i.prompt" required>
                        <textarea v-if="i.type == 'textarea'" class="w-100" row="5" v-model="i.value" :id="i.prompt"  :placeholder="i.prompt" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Introduzca un {{i.prompt}} correcto
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Enviar
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Y el prop template que recibe como prop tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
template:
data:
 0:  
   name: "title"
   prompt:   "Título"
   value:     ""
   type: "text"
 1:  
   name: "author"
   prompt:   "Autor"
   value:    ""
   type: "text"
 2:  
  name:  "description"
  prompt:    "Descripción"
  value: ""
  type:  "textarea"
 3:
  name:  "isbn"
  prompt:    "ISBN"
  value: ""
  type:  "text"
4:   
  name:  "image"
  prompt:    "Imagen de portada"
  value: ""
  type:  "text"
5:   
  name:  "datePublished"
  prompt:    "Fecha de publicación"
  value: ""
  type:  "date"
```

Ahora mismo las variables que tengo declaradas son:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            visible: false,
            isValidated: false,
            //Aquí irian las variables del formulario, que no sé como declarar
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido solucionarlo. El error lo tenía en que no estaba haciendo la llamada al método de validación en el lugar correcto y por eso no me tomaba bien las variables del objeto.